# List of pages and their type in SitePages Library using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export

How to get a list of all pages in the SitePages Library and their type using PowerShell?

I have created the pages, some are wiki pages and webpart pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Script:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb SiteUrl
$listName = "Site Pages"
 $list = $spWeb.Lists |? {$_.Title -eq $listName}
  foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
  {
  Write-Host $item["ContentType"]
  }
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script prints pages information from `Site Pages` library:

```
Get-SPWeb http://contoso.intranet.com/ |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Where { $_.Title -eq "Site Pages" } |
Select -ExpandProperty Items |
Select Name, url, {$_["ContentType"]}
```

Comment: I am checking this in PnP powershell i am not getting the ContentType name for each list item